# A multitude of the same id in an WHERE id IN () statement

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query that increases the value of a field by 1. 
Now I used to loop over all id's and fire a query for each of them, but now that things are getting a bit resource heavy I wanted to optimize this. Normally I would just do

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id IN (all the ids here)
```

but now I have the problem that there are id's that occur twice (or more, I can't know that on forehand).
Is there a way to have the query run twice for id 4 if the query looks like this:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Thanks,

lordstyx

Edit: sorry for not being clear enough.
The id here is an auto inc field, so it are all unique ID's. the id's that have to be updated are indirectly comming from users, so I can't predict which id is going to occur how often.
If there are the ID's (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5) I need the field of row with id 4 to be incremented with 2, and all the rest with 1.

Comment: What you mean "run twice"?  If field = 8 for the rows whose ID = 4, do you want that field to be set to 10 in both rows? Or to 9 in the first one and to 10 in the second row? Or do you simply want both rows whose ID = 4 to get incremented by 1, so the field value would be 9 for both? Also, you shouldn't think of the update statement as a "loop over".  You are acting upon the *SET* of rows.

Comment: @Tim: I bet that `id` is a PK so there is only one row with particular `id`.

Comment: I've edited the main post so that it's more clear (I hope)

Comment: "It's input generated (indirectly) by users" - what does this mean. is it inpossible to process the input? what language do you use and isn't it dangerous to use unprocessed input from user. what if users don't enter 1,2,3, but enter "1,2); delete from `table`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)` comes from a `SELECT id ...` query, then you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT id
           , COUNT(id) AS counter 
      ....
      GROUP BY id
    ) AS data
    ON yourTable.id = data.id
SET yourTable.field = yourTable.field + data.counter 
;
```

Since the input comes from users, perhaps you can manipulate it a bit. Change `(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)` to `(1), (2), (3), (4), (4), (5)`.

Then (having created a temporary table):

```
CREATE TABLE tempUpdate
( id INT )
;
```

Do the following procedure:

1. add the values in the temporary table,
2. run the update and
3. delete the values.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO TempUpdate
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (4), (5)
;

UPDATE yourTable 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT id
           , COUNT(id) AS counter 
      FROM TempUpdate
      GROUP BY id
    ) AS data
    ON yourTable.id = data.id
SET yourTable.field = yourTable.field + data.counter 
;

DELETE FROM TempUpdate
;
```

Comment: "It's input generated (indirectly) by users"

Comment: My appologies for not being clear, thanks for your response anyway!

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could perform something like

```
UPDATE table
   SET field = field + (LENGTH(',1,2,3,4,4,5,') - LENGTH(REPLACE(',1,2,3,4,4,5,', CONCAT(',', id, ','), ''))) / LENGTH(CONCAT(',', id, ','))
 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

if you need row with id = 4 specifically to be incremented twice

Comment: Yes well that's the problem. It's input generated (indirectly) by users and I can't know whether it's 4 that has to be incremented twice, or even trice, or more or not at all. (I could count, but that'd result in more than one query and loops in my code etc)

Comment: @lordstyx: if the list of ids come as a string - then you can follow the dirty trick I've shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Alright that's cool! Just a question, if that string contains about 1000 id's, is it performance wise still better to use that?

Comment: @lordstyx: 1. note that i've changed a little a string, adding commas in the start and in the end, and changed a lookup string a little, now it is `CONCAT(',', id, ',')`. 2. For 1000 items list (1 .. 1000) 10000 lookups took 0.83 seconds to perform on celeron 1.8ghz.

Comment: Thank you zerkms. I tested the query and for the id's that occured only once inside the string it would nicely update the string, but if it occured multiple times it'd update the field with the amount of occurance -1. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @lordstyx: give the sample of query.

Comment: Well it was just

UPDATE table
   SET field = field + (LENGTH(',67,67,67,70,71,75,') - LENGTH(REPLACE(',67,67,67,70,71,75,', CONCAT(',', id, ','), ''))) / LENGTH(CONCAT(',', id, ','))
 WHERE id IN (67, 67, 67, 70, 71, 75)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution you wanted, but I'm not sure this is what you need.

Let's say that your talbe is called `test`. You want to increase id. I've added a field idwas to easily show what was the id before the query:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `idwas` int(8) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ;
```

Let's fill it with data:

```
truncate table test;
insert into test(id) VALUES(1),(3),(15);
update test set idwas = id;
```

Now let's say that you have user input `1,3,5,3`, so:

- id 1 should be increased by 1
- id 3 should be increased by 2
- id 5 is missing, nothing to increase.
- row with id 15 should not be changed because not in user input

We'll put the user input in a variable to be easier to use it:

```
SET @userInput = '1,3,5,3';
```

then do the magic:

```
SET @helperTable = CONCAT(
  'SELECT us.id, count(us.id) as i FROM  ',
  '(SELECT ',REPLACE(@userInput, ',',' AS `id` UNION ALL SELECT '),
  ') AS us GROUP BY us.id');

SET @stmtText = CONCAT(
  ' UPDATE  ',
  '(',@helperTable,') AS h INNER JOIN test as t ON t.id = h.id',
  ' SET t.id = t.id + h.i');

PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtText;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

And this is the result:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------+
| id | idwas |
+----+-------+
|  2 |     1 |
|  5 |     3 |
| 15 |    15 |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's reasonable, you could try doing a combination of what you had before and what you have now.

In whatever is creating this list, separate it into (depending on the language's constructs) some type of array.  Follow this by sorting it,finding how many multiples of each there are, and doing whatever else you need to to get the following: an array with (increment-number => list of ids), so you do one query for each increment amount.  Thus, your example becomes

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 5)
UPDATE table SET field = field + 2 WHERE id IN (4)
```

In php, for example, I would take the array, sort the array, use the content of the array as the keys for another array of the form (id => count), and then fold that over into the (count => list of ids) array.

It's not that efficient, but is definitely better than one query per id.  It's also probably better than using iteration and string manipulation in SQL.  Unless you're forced to use SQL to do everything (which it sounds like you're not), I wouldn't use it to do everything, when it's overly awkward to do so.

Comment: Yes I thought about this in the first place. Somehow I thought that having 1 query for it would be quicker, but I don't know about that yet. Currently I do what ypercube gave, it reduced the executing time by about 80%, but yeah, the quicker the better of course!

Comment: In that case just give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
create temporary table temp1 (id integer);
insert into temp1 (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5);
update your_table set your_field = your_field + (select count(*) from temp1 where id = your_table.id)
```

This solution requires you to format the id list like (1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5) but I don't think that is a problem, right? 
This worked on my test database, hope it works for you too!

Regards,
Arthur